# Обработка нажатия на home-button при использовании NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Я использую NavigationDrawer для навигации между фрагментами. Если в обычном режиме нажатие на кнопку R.id.home показывает NavigationDrawer, то при переходе к определенному SecondFragment  мне нужно чтобы при нажатии этой кнопки я возвращался к  StartFragment (вместо отображения drawer`а). 
Пробовал это сделать в SecondFragment так :

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            StartFragment startFragment = new StartFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.content_frame, startFragment).commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Не работает. NavigationDrawer реализован в  MainActivity. Подскажите, как изменить событие нажатия этой кнопки. Я так  думаю,  это нужно как то описать в слушателях drawerToogle,но не понимаю как

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected у вас в классе фрагмента? Если да, то надо сей код перенести в класс активити.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб если в активити просто прописать этот код,то он не будет работать. тут по-идее из-за  drawerToogle

Comment: Как бы так в двух словах-то рассказать... Вам надо бы переопределить onBackPressed. В нём определять какой фрагмент отображается. Если изначальный - закрыть приложение. Если не он - вернуться по стеку фрагментов. Если при этом открыт дровер - закрыть его. При замене первого фрагмента на к-л другой надо менять иконку дровера на стрелку. В обработчике нажатия тоже определять закрытость дровера и какой фрагмент отображается...